# Surface integrals of scalars

Tags: multivariable-calculus, integration, definite-integrals

just having trouble with this question:

> Find $\iint_s z\,dS$ where $s$ is the triangular plate with vertices $(1,0,0)$, $(0,2,0)$, and $(0,1,1)$.

I started by getting the two vectors between the points and getting the normal.

I ended up getting $\sqrt{6}$ as the magnitude and $2x + y + z = 2$ as the plane.

Now this is the point where I'm not fully sure. I projected onto the $x$-$y$ plane and attempted to get the boundaries for integration. But as the points go up to $z=1$ I'm not sure if I should have done that:

$$0\le y\le 2-2x$$
$$0\le x\le 1$$

I took the integral and I got $\frac{2}{\sqrt{6}}$, but the answer is sadly $\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}$.

I'm not sure where to go from there. I find it really difficult to visualize these boundaries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so after extensive thought I have come up with a more refined answer, the existing plane is fine, but because of its position, to integrate it as a function of x and y, or a function of z and x would be very messy seeing as the plane must then be cut into two different planes instead. Noting this i found that it is actually best to orient the usual Cartesian plane so that x points upwards, z points out of the paper and y points to the right (so as to preserve the normal right handed sense of the axes) in this regard the plan takes on the definition 
$$ x = 1 - \frac{1}{2}y - \frac{1}{2}z$$
Thus the new definition of the surface integral becomes
$$ \int \int f(x(y,z), y ,z) \sqrt{ \left(\frac{\partial x}{ \partial y} \right)^2 + \left(\frac{\partial x}{ \partial z} \right)^2 + 1 } d A $$
Using the above definition of the plane we have the partial derivatives are:
\begin{eqnarray*}
\left(\frac{\partial x}{ \partial y} \right)^2 &=& \frac{1}{4} \\
\left(\frac{\partial x}{ \partial z} \right)^2 &=& \frac{1}{4} \\
\end{eqnarray*}
so that the square root as you almost correctly calculated is $ \frac{\sqrt{6}}{2}$
Now for the bounds involving y and z, draw the y-z plane with y on the vertical axis ( in a similar way you might draw x horizontal and y vertical, like you are treating z as the x axis) The resulting shape is a triangular region made of the two lines
\begin{eqnarray*}
 y &=& z \; \text { (lower bound)} \\
 y &=& 2 - z \; \text{ (upper bound)} \\
\end{eqnarray*}
Thus we have that for the double integral over the area is given by
$$ \int_{0}^{1} \int_{z}^{2-z} z \frac{\sqrt{6}}{2}dydz $$
If you compute this integral you should find the correct answer of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}$

Answer (score 1):

your y parameter is incorrect Jesse, the limit of y is $$ 1-x \le y \le 2-2x$$ Now your integral will work. So your new integral will be $$\int_0^1 \int_{1-x}^{2-2x} \frac{x}{\frac{1}{\sqrt6}} dy dx$$

ps: Melb uni all day :p hahah just did this question about 30mins ago lol ;)

have a look: http://www.cds.caltech.edu/~marsden/wiki/uploads/math1c-08/assignments/ma1chw7-2008.pdf